# After Effects applyPreset : bad path

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

So I'm totally new to ExtendScript, and already amazed. I've been trying to automatize the creation of standard videos, and to do so I want to create presets and apply them to footage. So I use the applyPreset(File) method of the layers.

The new File("path") seems to open fine, but then applyPreset is unhappy because it tells me my path is wrong. Namely, After Effects says "Unable to call applyPreset because of parameter 1 : incorrect path "/Users/Charles/Documents/Slide-In-1.ffx"". Yet my path, I can assure you, is absolutely correct. Being on Mac, I used "~/Documents/Slide-In-1.ffx", which got replaced by "/Users/Charles/Documents/Slide-In-1.ffx" according to the error output (this replacement is correct, clearly). So where's the problem ? How can I check that a file has indeed been found and opened by JavaScript ? Thanks a lot in advance.

Charles

Comment: Seems my path was in fact bad. Something fishy, but I had to change my file organisation anyway to have a clean centralized git repo, and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Seems my path was in fact bad. Something fishy, but I had to change my file organisation anyway to have a clean centralized git repo, and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

you can test if a file exists like this:

```
if( File(YOURPATH).exists )
```

> If true, this object refers to a file or file-system alias that actually exists in the file system.
>   http://jongware.mit.edu/Js/pc_File.html